# Edge Animate - Scaling misplaces scrollbar on IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, adobe-edge, nicescroll

I've inherited an Edge Animate project. The project uses [nicescroll.js](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll) on a text panel.

In IE9, when the animation is scaled up to fill the window, the position of the nicescroll scroller is misplaced.

Does anyone have any advice about how I might be able to combat this? Or alternatively, is it possible to disable scaling entirely in some older browsers?

*ANY* advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used a different scroller that was purely css based.